# How to getdate minus 1 day SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, expression

How can I get the day before today in a SSIS expression?
I have this expression that gives me the current day

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()),2 + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()),2)
```

It doesn't matter the day of the week, I only need to back in time one day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DATEADD() Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/dateadd-ssis-expression)

```
DATEADD("dd", -1,GETDATE())
```

Given the expression you included in your question, it would look like this:

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2)+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2)
```

**Alternate Package Solution**

Rather than repeating DATEADD()..3 times, use a reference to a Variable whose Expression result is "yesterday".

Create a DateTime variable named Yesterday [@User::Yesterday]. In that variable, place the expression:

```
DATEADD("dd", -1,GETDATE())
```

Then create a 2nd Variable and reference [@User::Yesterday] in that:

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[User::Yesterday]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::Yesterday]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[User::Yesterday]), 2)
```

[image]

By the way, if you were not able to get your posted SSIS Expression to work, it was missing just one parenthesis:

[image]